# CALayer sublayer hides the parent layer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, calayer

I have a single `CALayer` subclass, and in it I generate one sublayer. The problem I have is that once I add `[layer addSublayer:layer.childLayer]` the layer to it's parent, it hides it by covering the space with itself.

I've tried changing `zPosition` and all other insert layer methods, but to no effect. Why am I seeing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublayer (or Subviews) are always drawn 'above' their super layer (or Superview). Of course, because the superview acts as the container for the subview. 
You won't be able to change that behavior by zPosition or `[insertSublayer:atIndex:]`

The only thing you can do to hide the sublayer is by setting it's `opacity` value to 0 ..

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve .. maybe you could give us a bit more context ?

Comment: This certainly gave me enough insight to solve my issue, thanks!